# Django: UnicodeEncodeError while parsing xml with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, django

I'm trying to fetch products catalog from xml file with cyrilic characters. I parsed it with ElementTree, got the data and tried to save it to database, but I got an encoding error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://detsad-komplekt.loc/catalog/commerce/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
(u'admin_tools',
 u'admin_tools.theming',
 u'admin_tools.menu',
 u'admin_tools.dashboard',
 u'django.contrib.admin',
 u'django.contrib.auth',
 u'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 u'django.contrib.sessions',
 u'django.contrib.messages',
 u'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 u'mptt',
 u'daguerre',
 u'ckeditor',
 u'home',
 u'accounts',
 u'catalog',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'coverage')
Installed Middleware:
(u'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/detsad-komplekt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/detsad-komplekt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/detsad-komplekt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/detsad-komplekt/project/catalog/views.py" in get
  109.         cat = parseCML()
File "/home/oleshko/design/detsad-komplekt/project/catalog/tools.py" in parseCML
  21.         name = name.decode('utf8', 'ignore')
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/detsad-komplekt/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py" in decode
  16.     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /catalog/commerce/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my function:

```
def parseCML():
    with open('/home/oleshko/desktop/webdata/import.xml', 'r') as xml_file:
        tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    elems = root[1][4]
    res = []
    for prod in elems:
        for cat in prod[4]:
            c = Category.objects.filter(integration_id=cat.text)       
        name = prod[2].text
        name = name.decode('utf8', 'ignore')
        desc = prod[5].text
        desc = desc.decode('utf8', 'ignore')
        img = str(prod[6].text)
        img = img.replace('import_files', '')
        slug = pytils.translit.slugify(name)
        # res.append([c, name, desc, img, '################'])
        product = Product(name=name, slug=slug, category=c, description=desc, price=1)
        new_product = product.save()
        prod_img = ProductImage(product=new_product, src=img)

    return True
```

I lost 4 hours already trying to solve this problem. Please, give any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:
c = Category.objects.filter(integration_id=cat.text)
I forgot that it returns queryset instead of category instance, decoding error occured somewhere while dropping exeption. Thanks for user 'catavaran'